# How to test my own ASP.NET Web API in localhost:port using android or Windows Phone device (no simulator)

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, windows-phone-7, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to develop my first REST Service using ASP.NET following this [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api).
I'd like to test my services in localhost using my android and wp devices without using android and WP simulator (too slow).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deploy the ASP.NET app on IIS, the services will be reachable as long as the phones are connected on the same network (via Wifi for example). Just use the IP adress of the server instead of `localhost`.

Comment: And probably will need some Firewall configuration as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use fiddler's proxy option. (This also assumes you have set up your app in IIS). Check out [this article](http://conceptdev.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html?m=1).

This approach is especially useful if you want to test using custom host headers over SSL.

With this approach you can simulate production dns (by altering hosts file on the fiddler host) rather than using IP addresses and machine names from the mobile device.